# How do I open files from a list of directory paths?

Tags: python, directory, os.walk

I have a list of folders that I need to open and read a .log file. 
At first, I did not have the list of folders, so I was scanning all the files in the directory. This will lead to redundancy for what I want to use this for.

```
path = '/home/User/Test/'
files = []

# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.log' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    log_file = open(f, 'r')

    lines = log_file.readlines()
    log_file.close()
```

Now, I have a list `paths` which look like `['/home/User/Test/folder_test/Process1/Task1/2019-07-31T10%3A30%3A00+00%3A00', ...., 'final_path']`

How can I loop through the paths so it is opening the folder, at then extracting the .log file?

NOTE: I am getting rid of `path = '/home/User/Test/'` as I have the list of specific directories.

Comment: by adding another loop at the top iterating over list of paths ?

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to walk through different directory and if you find log file read the file. right?

Comment: @Poojan, yes I want to walk through each directory in the list and if I find a log file, read the file.

Comment: then just change `files.append(os.path.join(r, file))` to `logfile = open(os.path.join(r, file));lines = logfile.readlineas();logfile.close()`

Comment: @poojan I think I need to change the first part of the for loop... I need to have a list of files, which is why I have an empty list that I am appending.

Comment: @CorentinLimier.  I tried adding ```for path in paths: ``` above the loop. That actually makes sense, but it is not working.  I am going to put some new test folders in my directory. Because my program does a lot of different things.

Comment: `is not working` is a bit broad, please edit your question with the exact error. `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.` (The Zen of Python)

Comment: @CorentinLimier ... My program at large scans log files and pulls out key insights. Currently, I am only looking folders that were modified today, to reduce redundancy. I am about to add new folders into the directory.

Comment: @CorentinLimier  It is not able to add anything to the files list. I print it and it is empty. There's no way the list should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can utilize the [glob library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for this problem. It allows you to pattern-match your paths.